# Asked question as guest, answered question on a beta Stack Exchange site with using my Facebook account. In a redirection loop

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

I asked a question on *[English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)* as a guest user. I then answered a question on a beta Stack Exchange site (*[Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tour)* - my professional expertise). I chose to sign in via Facebook to answer a question I could help with.

I am now trying to complete my sign in to participate on *English Language & Usage* and cannot. I have tried using the "sign in with Facebook" link to no avail.

Should I delete my account with *Arts & Crafts*?

The confirmation email I receive says, "Almost done! Click here to complete your registration."

Click → I'm sent to Stack Exchange saying, "Forgot your password?"

I would rather not go through Facebook and use my guest name, but it is already linked to my Facebook email.

Comment: You need to merge your two accounts. See the faq to know how to do that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It might still be the problem, but did you note that the accounts (this one, the A&C account and the EL&U account) are already linked together in the account section of the user profile?

Comment: @wythagoras yeah, that is weird, but still - the unregistered account should somehow be merged with the full account, and only SE team can do that. The faq explains how to contact the team for that, and they will handle it.